# Is there a word for "making a pupil stand up in the back of class as punishment"?

Tags: word-request

Is there a verb for "making a pupil stand up in the back of class as punishment"? As in:

Jack misbehaved yesterday. The teacher *verbed*  him for 20 minutes

In Arabic we would say "yZZANIB", I've checked my (bilingual) dictionary and there is no entry for this verb.

Comment: Is there a single word in any language you know? Have you checked a bilingual dictionary?  I'm not sure about all schools, but this is not a common form of punishment in most UK schools.

Comment: Yes there is a single word in Arabic, "yZZANIB".

Comment: Have you checked a bilingual dictionary?

Comment: I have. There is no entry for the Arabic word

Comment: Get a better dictionary!  Not much point in a dictionary that doesn't have the words you want to use.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a common form of punishment in English schools, and there is no single verb. You would have to say "The teacher made him stand at the back of class for twenty minutes."

Some schools will have a "time-out" space, not as a punishment *per se*, but as a way of reducing conflict. You might say "The teacher sent him to timeout for twenty minutes".

A more common punishment is detention during break or after school. In this case you can say "The teacher detained him for twenty minutes after school".

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it is always

- The teacher **made him stand in the corner** for 20 minutes
- The teacher **made him stand at the back** for 20 minutes

and similar.

Comment: In modern parlance, this would probably be called a *time out*, e.g. *the teacher gave him a time out*, but when I was growing up in the 1980s in Southern California, we would indeed just say *the teacher made him stand in the corner*. Twenty minutes seems like an exceptionally long time, however.